# when concatenating two xsl variables i get : An XPath expression was expected to return a NodeSet

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

Hello everyone let us say i have the following xml:

```
<root>
    <leader>
        <paragraph>
             first
        </paragraph>

        <paragraph>
             second
        </paragraph>
    </leader>

    <sub>
        <paragraph>
            third
        </paragraph>

        <paragraph>
            fourth
        </paragraph>
    </sub>
</root>
```

I then specify in my xsl some variables as such:

```
<xsl:variable name="first" select="root/leader/paragraph/text()" />
<xsl:variable name="second" select="root/sub/paragraph/text()" />
<xsl:variable name="third">
    <xsl:value-of select="$first" />
    <xsl:value-of select="$second" />
</xsl:variable>
```

I would then expect the output to have concatenated all the text from all paragraph eleemtns together instead i get:

An XPath expression was expected to return a NodeSet

I am using xsl v2.0

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you are using an XSLT 2.0 processor? And are you sure you get that error message for any of those lines of code? And for which line exactly? Where and how do you use the variable `$third`?

Comment: I use third to place that data (which i assume to be a concatonation of all paragraphs, i.e the result should be 'one two three four') into a new node so:

Comment: <newNode><xsl:value-of select="$third" /></newNode>

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with those snippets. Which XSLT processor gives that error message, for which line of code?

Comment: The reference to the term "node set" in the error message suggests you are in fact using an XSLT 1.0 processor, not 2.0.  That being the case I'd expect the `$third` variable to contain just the text "first third" (possibly with additional intervening whitespace).

Comment: (because `$first` and `$second` are node sets that each contain two text nodes, and in XSLT 1.0 the `value-of` a node set is the string value of only the _first_ node in the set in document order)

Comment: Thankyou very much gents, i am an idiot and was indeed running an xslt 1.0 processor, i thankyou and apologise for using up your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still join the text nodes in XSLT 1.0, using a handy template that loops (`for-each`) over the text nodes. Alternatively, a recursive template could be used to achieve the same.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="root"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:variable name="first" select="root/leader/paragraph/text()" />
  <xsl:variable name="second" select="root/sub/paragraph/text()" />
  <xsl:variable name="third" select="$first|$second"/>

  <xsl:template match="root">
    <joined-string>
      <xsl:call-template name="join">
        <xsl:with-param name="list" select="$third"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </joined-string>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="join">
    <xsl:param name="list" />
    <xsl:param name="separator" select="' '"/>

    <xsl:for-each select="$list">
      <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)" />
      <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
        <xsl:value-of select="$separator" />
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<joined-string>first second third fourth</joined-string>
```

If you want all text nodes of all paragraphs, I recommend the following simplified template:

```
  <xsl:template match="root">
    <joined-string>
      <xsl:call-template name="join">
        <xsl:with-param name="list" select="//paragraph/text()"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </joined-string>
  </xsl:template>
```